# как обратиться к src по классу через js

Tags: javascript

Пример:

```
<div class="image"><img src="https://pictures.net/kartinka.jpg" id="img">
```

Как обратиться к src класса или айдишника?  Смысл в том, что я хочу заменить srс. Если к bg например я могу обратиться  image.style.backgroundImage ,то как заменить src  не пойму.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.querySelector(".image img").src = 'https://pictures.net/kartinka.jpg';
```

Comment: хорошо. а если я не знаю какая у меня ссылка будет там 

Пример:

<div class="image"><img src="??" id="img">

Comment: `let link = document.querySelector(".image img").src;` - получить ссылку, в ответе это в src записывается ссылка

Comment: понял. спасибо большое за помощь